# Ubuntu unable to install .Net Core

Tags: linux, ubuntu, .net-core

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on virtual machine and trying to install .Net core.

I have followed following link for [Installing .Net Core on Ubuntu](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#ubuntu)

I tried to install package but it's failing.

Here is snapshot please check it once.
[image]

After installing Ubuntu 16.04 i found that .Net core is still not supported in 16.04 and maximum support is provide is up to 15.10.

[Ubuntu - Installing .net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322843/ubuntu-installing-net-core)

Why there is no note on Installing .Net core in Ubuntu page about what version of Ubuntu should be used?

Is it correct that .Net Core is still not supported in Ubuntu 16.04? Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: I suggest you ask Ubuntu.

Comment: "Why there is no note on Installing .Net core in Ubuntu page about what version of Ubuntu should be used?" There is, right under the menu, in large font: "Install for Ubuntu 14.04".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37346387/3578677
refer this link, hope it will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation has been updated.

And now [Installing .NetCore on linux](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#ubuntu) provides separate command that can be used to install .NetCore on Ubuntu 16.04.

Please check it once.

Comment: I followed the instructions at the link to try to install dotnet on a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04, and get this error when I try to run `dotnet new`: Updating 'libhostfxr.so' to version '1.0.2-beta-000583-00' might help resolve this problem.

Comment: @Number8 have you solved your problem? If not there is already script available on above site to remove all .Net version. and try to reinstall it using Aptitude.https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/aptitude.html

Comment: Do you want to accept this answer instead of mine, since it's not correct anymore?

Comment: I have changed accepted answer. Is it okay? Your answer is also correct but they updated their documents after couple of days i asked question.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is no package available for `dotnet` on Ubuntu 16.04. But you can build it yourself by cloning the [dotnet/cli](https://github.com/dotnet/cli) repository and then following [this guide](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/rel/1.0.0/Documentation/developer-guide.md).

Doing that seems to work for me on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Hello @svick. Sorry but i am completely new to Linux environment and .NetCore. Can you tell me what's the difference between "xenial" and "trusty". I mean is it kind of complete separate repository?

Comment: @NiravKamani Those are [code names for Ubuntu versions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). Trusty is 14.04, Xenial is 16.04.