# install .NET on ubuntu 15.10 failed

Tags: .net, ubuntu

When installing .NET on ubuntu 15.10 using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2-003121.
```

It gives the following error:

[image]

any help here?

Comment: Simply install those dependencies and see if it works out. Go ask this question here: http://askubuntu.com

Comment: i found the solution here and it worked http://stackoverflow.com/a/37346387/3578677

Answer (score 0):

The rule of Linux is that you must be using a LTS release or the latest current release, as this page shows,

https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxubuntu

So in your case, switch to a supported Ubuntu release is step 1.