# Installing .net core on ubuntu

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I downloaded .net core file and got it in the form of tar.gz
I then extracted in to a particular folder. Inside it, when I double click on dotnet file (to maybe install it), nothing happens!

Please help. 
I need it to run Visual studio code

Comment: What is "visual studio code"?  Visual studio is an IDE, not a programming language

Comment: @StephenC Visual Studio Code _is_ [an IDE now](https://code.visualstudio.com/) - they perhaps could have come up with a more unambiguous name, but it's a pretty good IDE.

Comment: Anyway: https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/linuxubuntu

Comment: And https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux

Comment: @StephenC my main problem is .net core related

Comment: "dotnet" is not the installer, it's the command line to invoke dotnet commands (build, run, etc).  What happens when you run it in a shell?

Comment: I meant the dotnet core sdk I get it in tar.gz format but after extracting it and clicking the icon nothing happens. I probably should ask this question in ubuntu site.

Comment: For now, the the way to install it in the description given in the link provided by Stephen works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu - Installing .net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322843/ubuntu-installing-net-core)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing the .NET Core SDK and runtime on an ubuntu machine can be quite daunting if you don't have much experience with Linux distributions.

But the steps are outlined on the official .NET Core website (which is available here https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/linuxubuntu) quite well, in my opinion.

*side note: I know that a lot of Linux set up can be daunting and seem like a dark art to folks who are new to it.*

Depending on which version of Ubuntu you have, you'll need to run slightly different steps. I run Unbuntu 17.04, for instance, so the commands that I would run in the terminal (which is the Command Prompt if you're from a Windows background) are:

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg
sudo mv microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg
```

This will install Microsoft's secure key into your system and allow your system to install their packages.

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-zesty-prod zesty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list'
```

This adds the package list for Microsoft's builds of .NET Core to the list of sources that your Ubuntu installation can install packages and application from. It's also the only step which appears to be different depending on which version of Ubuntu you are running.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.0.2
```

The first command here tells Ubuntu's package manager (`apt-get`) to update it's list of available packages (from the list we just updated).

The second command here is the important one, it's the one which installs the .NET Core SDK onto your computer.

Once this has completed (it might take a while), you can run commands like:

```
dotnet new console -o myApp
```

Which will create a Console Application project called `myApp` in a directory called `myApp`.

From there you can open the project with any IDE which supports .NET Core. I'd recommend either [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) with the C# extension by OmniSharp, or [Rider by Jet Brains](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/) (there is a cost to this though, as it is not a free IDE).

Tiny bit of self promotion here, but  I've written about getting it all set up before, in case you're interested in reading about it - [here is a link to it](https://dotnetcore.gaprogman.com/2016/10/05/first-steps/). It's from 2016, so some of the version numbers will have changed. But most of the information is the same.

#### Note to moderators, admins and community members

I do not mind at all, if the final paragraph of my answer is edited out. I just thought that it would be a useful resource to include. I'll leave it to the community to decide, but I wanted to be up front about it being self-promotion as it linked to a blog that I run. Apologies if this breaks the rules or guidelines.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with promoting your own blog post in an answer so long as the answer would still be considered a complete answer if the link was deleted (which your post is)

Comment: Thank you @ScottChamberlain I'll bear that in mind for any future answers.